# How to separate a tuple into two independant lists?

Tags: python, split, tuples

I would like to separate the following tuple into two lists

```
(('happy', 5.001), ('neutral', 10.004), ('neutral', 15.006), ('happy', 20.071), 
 ('fear', 25.071))
```

I want my lists to look like the following:

```
a = ('happy', 'neutral', 'neutral', 'happy', 'fear')
b = (5.001, 10.004, 15.006, 20.071, 25.071)
```

The `split()` method is not working on this.

Comment: `split()` is a string method, not a tuple method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here comes your new hero, the `zip` function!

```py
l = (('happy', 5.001), ('neutral', 10.004), ('neutral', 15.006), ('happy', 20.071), ('fear', 25.071))
a, b = zip(*l)
```

For future usages, we could say that it works in two different modes:

- `zip(*iterable)` generates *n* iterables (being *n* the size of every tuple in the iterable), where every iterable contains the *ith* element of each tuple (**the example of my answer**).
- `zip(iterable_1, ..., iterable_n)` generates a single iterable where every element is a tuple of size *n* containing the element of every iterable at the corresponding index.

Answer (score 0):

```
t = (('happy', 5.001), ('neutral', 10.004), ('neutral', 15.006), ('happy', 20.071), ('fear', 25.071))
a = [x[0] for x in t]
b = [x[1] for x in t]
```

This uses list comprehension to address the problem. It creates list 'a' using first element(index 0) from each tuple in 't' while creates list 'b' using the second element(index 1).

Comment: I assume shasha0607 want lists though in the sample output tuples are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
t = (('happy', 5.001), ('neutral', 10.004), ('neutral', 15.006), ('happy', 20.071), ('fear', 25.071))
a, b = zip(*t)
```

Answer (score 0):

to do what you want you can just do the following

```
c = (('happy', 5.001), ('neutral', 10.004), ('neutral', 15.006), ('happy', 20.071), ('fear', 25.071))
a, b = zip(*c)
```

but in this case a and b are tuples not lists, lists are in this format :

```
a = ['happy', 'neutral', 'neutral', 'happy', 'fear']
b = [5.001, 10.004, 15.006, 20.071, 25.071]
```

you can just do list(a) to convert from tuple to list